# Wordpress: Missing the place of a deleted sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, themes

I have a problem with Wordpress. 
I let a sidebar disappear using style:display:none;

And now I want to use that place that was used by that sidebar.
For example: There is a text placed left and right was the sidebar.

And if I now set width:100% for that text it doesn't fill that used place of sidebar.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `display:none;` Why don't you remove that sidebar code from template ?

Comment: What kind of code you want me to share?

Comment: @SudharshanNair because I need it for other pages.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma If you want me to share some code then tell what code you want me to share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
My theme used flex. So I changed everything about flex and used that place used for sidebar.

The problem is that I should have build everything else with flex. Therefor I didn't use that and instead I put that information I wanted to use in that place of sidebar in the sidebar and modified it with placeholder sidebar element. It is not the perfect way, but it works ;)